# Vector Values (String and Int) Summation C++

Tags: python, c++, list, vector, sum

I have moved to C++ from Python, and just wanted to know the way to sum the values that a vector (list) object holds. For example, in python, I could use the code below:

```
totalSum = 0
myList = [1,2,3,4,5]

for i in myList:
    totalSum += i

print(totalSum)
// Output:
15
```

However, I want to learn the way to do this in C++

```
totalSum = ""
myList = ["Hello", "World!"]

for i in myList:
    totalSum += i
    totalSum += " "

print(totalSum)
//Output:
Hello World!
```

And this one is for the string combination.

Could you please provide how to do this in c++?

I have tried the code below in C++ to test, however, it does not compile successfully:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    
    // A random list/vector here:
    vector <double> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    // Declaring the final string to gather all the vector values:
    int sum;

    // Iterating through the vector
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        sum += v[i];
    }
    
    cout << sum;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you maybe looking for [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)?

Comment: does that also work with strings?

Comment: If you can come up with something that describes what it means to accumulate / sum up strings and provide a suitable functor for that, then sure.

Comment: Why doesn't the code compile? What errors do you get?

Comment: just a regular vs debugger error

Comment: This also works, and is closer to python
    `for (auto i : v) sum += i;`

Comment: is not there any way in c++ to use the summation using iterators? that sounds kind of impossible actually that there does not exist such thing

Comment: What is a 'regular vs debugger' error?

Comment: std::accumulate uses iterators, or you could write your own loop using iterators. Not sure where you are getting you ideas from. Maybe you are just using 'iterator' in a different way to how it is used in C++.

Comment: "There were build errors. Would you like to continue and run the last successful build?"

Comment: Change `int sum;` to `int sum = 0;`. That's the only error I can see.

Comment: alright @john , thank you so much for your support, will be testing it out rn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program has an error. In the `for` loop, you're trying to compare an integer to an `unsigned long long int` which is returned by `v.size()` (use `-Wall` mode in the compiler arguments to get it).

Using for each syntax, an approach is defined as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(void) {
    std::vector <std::string> v = {"Hello", "World"};
    std::string sum;

    for (auto i : v) {
        sum += i;
        sum += ' ';
    }
    
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This will print:

```
Hello World
```

Comment: Exactly man, that is what I was looking for, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine except for the fact you haven't initialized sum variable.

Here is some self-explanatory code discussing what you can use (based on the comments on your question):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    // For strings:

    std::string str;
    std::vector<std::string> v = {"Hello", "World!"};

    // Method 1: Using range-based for loop:
    for (auto &&i : v) {
        str += i;
        str += " ";
    }
    std::cout << str << std::endl;

    // Method 2: Using std::accumulate():
    str = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), std::string(), [](std::string a, std::string b) {
        return std::move(a) + b + " ";
    });
    std::cout << str << std::endl;

    // Method 3: The usual for-loop:
    str = "";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        str += v.at(i); // str += v[i];
        str += " ";
    }
    std::cout << str << std::endl;

    // Method 4: Using iterators:
    str = "";
    for (auto i = v.begin(); i < v.end(); ++i) { // for (auto i = std::begin(v); i < std::end(v); std::advance(i))
        str += *i;
        str += " ";
    }
    std::cout << str << std::endl;

    // For numbers:

    std::vector<int> v2  = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int sum = 0;

    // Method 1: Using range-based for loop:
    for (auto &&i : v2)
        sum += i;
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;

    // Method 2: Using std::accumulate():
    sum = std::accumulate(v2.begin(), v2.end(), 0);
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;

    // Method 3: The usual for-loop:
    sum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v2.size(); ++i)
        sum += v2.at(i); // sum += v2[i]
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;

    // Method 4: Using iterators:
    sum = 0;
    for (auto i = v2.begin(); i < v2.end(); ++i) // for (auto i = std::begin(v2); i < std::end(v2); std::advance(i))
        sum += *i;
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

You can replace the argument list of lamda passed to `std::accumulate` to `(auto a, auto b)` from `(std::string a, std::string b)` if you are using C++14 or above.

You need to include `<iterator>` if you are using `std::begin()` or `std::end()` or `std::advance()`. Also you can remove `<numeric>` if you are not using `std::accumulate()`.

For documentation of any unfamiliar thing you see in my code, kindly visit https://en.cppreference.com/.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in the STL algorithms, you can achieve this by using [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate):

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector <double> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::cout << std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0) << "\n"; 

    std::vector<std::string> s = {"Hello", "World", "abc", "123"};
    std::cout << std::accumulate(s.begin(), s.end(), std::string(), 
                                [](auto& total, auto& str) { return total + str + " "; });  
}
```

Output:

```
15
Hello World abc 123
```

Comment: exactly, deeply appreciated